# R: DT (package) datatable export to Excel (xlsx) with proper formatting (colors of cells)

Tags: r, excel, datatable, xlsx, dt

I decided to post an official question because I could not find any solution to my problem with exporting a “datatable” generated by a R-package “DT”.

I would like to export a table with a time-series including colours of cells. I also present a small (replicable) example to explain what my problem is. Of course my real example is more complicated but if I am able to export this one (small) example to xlsx file it will also work with my. The idea is to export the whole table including formatting (colours of cells). Unfortunately, colours play enormous role in my analysis, I must somehow nicely mark that those results fulfil certain criteria

I already checked quite many options how to do it for instance using R-packages – openxlsx, xlsx, htmlTable etc. and also “ready-made” buttons in DT package. Unfortunately, in all attempts I was not able to get an excel file with proper formatting

Here is my small example:

```
library(DT)
options(DT.options = list(pageLength = 5))
df = as.data.frame(cbind(matrix(round(rnorm(50), 3), 10), sample(0:1, 10, TRUE)))

datatable(df) %>% formatStyle(
  'V1', 'V6',
  backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(0, 1), c('gray', 'yellow'))
)
```

I also tried ways presented on this webiste but without success... 
https://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html 
The ready made buttons do not generate Excel files with proper formatting.

And here the solution (not working for formatting) with buttons:

```
library(DT)
datatable(
  iris, extensions = 'Buttons', options = list(
    dom = 'Bfrtip',
    buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print')
  )
)
```

and here this solution combined with colours:

```
library(DT)
df = as.data.frame(cbind(matrix(round(rnorm(50), 3), 10), sample(0:1, 10, TRUE)))

datatable(df,, extensions = 'Buttons', options = list(
  dom = 'Bfrtip',
  buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print')
)) %>% formatStyle(
  'V1', 'V6',
  backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(0, 1), c('gray', 'yellow'))
)
```

I would be happy for any help, links etc, thank you in advance!

Comment: Why don't you just use conditional formatting in Excel?  You can export to a named range and record a Macro that selects the range and applies the formatting.  Using a named range allows you to export data of different dimensions.

Comment: @SteveM, thanks, yes, I did it already in the Excel. I just though that there is some (easy) ready-made solution like write.xlsx(x, .....), convert() etc with some R-package that I didnt discover yet :) I liked the DT package, it is quite easy to use even for me (not advanced programmer) so I though about using it in the future

Comment: I think there's a JavaScript library which allows to do that but this works only in Excel (the colors do not appear in LibreOffice). There's no ready-made solution for DT.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent, thank you!